# Convert wide dataset with many columns to long format

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below

```
    DF<-structure(list(Channel_title = c("Blippi Toys", "PewDiePie"), 
    Kids_13_and_under = c("TRUE", "FALSE"), `Teens_13-17` = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), Adults_17_and_older = c("FALSE", "FALSE"), `2018-03` = c(101163664, 
    222435612), `2018-04` = c(138215454, 217690060), `2018-05` = c(151697886, 
    254479194), `2018-06` = c(142169001, 297190999)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I would like to transform it in a way that will look like:

```
Channel_title   Month Views_for_that_month Kids_13_and_under Teens_13_17 Adults_17_and_older
1   Blippi Toys 2018-03            101163664              TRUE       FALSE               FALSE
2   Blippi Toys 2018-04            138215454              TRUE       FALSE               FALSE
3   Blippi Toys 2018-05            151697886              TRUE       FALSE               FALSE
4   Blippi Toys 2018-06            142169001              TRUE       FALSE               FALSE
5     PewDiePie 2018-03            222435612             FALSE        TRUE               FALSE
6     PewDiePie 2018-04            217690060             FALSE        TRUE               FALSE
7     PewDiePie 2018-05            254479194             FALSE        TRUE               FALSE
8     PewDiePie 2018-06            297190999             FALSE        TRUE               FALSE
```

with something like

```
long <- melt(setDT(DF), id.vars = colnames(DF), variable.name = "Channel_title")
```

my actual data has hundreds of months as columns

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format?rq=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)

cols <- grep("\\d{4}-\\d{2}", names(DF), value = TRUE)
pivot_longer(DF, cols = cols, names_to = "Month", values_to = "Views_for_that_month")
```

result:

```
  Channel_title Kids_13_and_under `Teens_13-17` Adults_17_and_older Month   Views_for_that_month
  <chr>         <chr>             <chr>         <chr>               <chr>                  <dbl>
1 Blippi Toys   TRUE              FALSE         FALSE               2018-03            101163664
2 Blippi Toys   TRUE              FALSE         FALSE               2018-04            138215454
3 Blippi Toys   TRUE              FALSE         FALSE               2018-05            151697886
4 Blippi Toys   TRUE              FALSE         FALSE               2018-06            142169001
5 PewDiePie     FALSE             TRUE          FALSE               2018-03            222435612
6 PewDiePie     FALSE             TRUE          FALSE               2018-04            217690060
7 PewDiePie     FALSE             TRUE          FALSE               2018-05            254479194
8 PewDiePie     FALSE             TRUE          FALSE               2018-06            297190999
```